# Solving a differential equation by Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am trying to solve:

$$y"+2y'+y = 0, y(0)=1,y'(0)=1$$

My work is shown below:

> $y''+2y'+y=0$, $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=1$
>
> $\mathcal L[y''+2y'+y]=\mathcal L(0)$
>
> $\mathcal L[y'']+2\mathcal L[y]'+\mathcal L[y]=0$
>
> $[s^2\mathcal L[y(s)]-sy(0)-y'(0)]+2[sx(s)-y(0)]+x(s)=0$
>
> $s^2x(s)-s-1+2sx(s)-2+x(s)=0$
>
> $x(s)(s^2+2s+1)=s+3$
>
> $x(s)=\frac{s+3}{s^2+2s+1}$

[image]

I don't see this particular problem online or any other site so it might help people on the same problem.

Any advice you might have as to how to proceed would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your question! For future reference, try to use MathJax to format your questions; link as to how to use it pasted here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It's $s+3$ ont the right side

Comment: I have tried to retype the text from your image. (Although in some places I was not able to read your handwriting.) This might help you get started with MathJax.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this 
$$\mathcal{L}(e^{at}t^n)=\frac {n!} {(s-a)^{n+1}}$$
And also 
$$\frac {s+3}{(s+1)^2}=\frac 1 {s+1}+\frac 2{(s+1)^2}$$

Comment: why s+3 and not s+2? where did you add the +1 to the right side, its the last term? y(s) = +1 ?

Comment: you forgot to multiply by 2 in $L(y')$ check your answer  @joshuauribe

Comment: ohh right my bad... thanks

Comment: Yw @joshuauribe no problem. Everything was correct except  for that factor 2

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, is the answer correct?

Answer is :

$$y(t)= e^{-t} + 2te^{-t}$$ 
not the one on the paper

Comment: is this what you meant ?  (No need to upload the pics again.)  It seems correct to me . But remeber that $(y(t)$ is now a function of $t$ . You are not anymore in the S-World

Comment: yes, i need to learn how to write like that.

Comment: That's correct. Good job !!

Comment: thank you so much isham.

Comment: yw joshua.........

Comment: Joshua if you need you can also edit any post ( answer or question) to see the latex mathjax code and learn by the way.